# open() serial device twice for read and write in multithread context

Tags: c, multithreading, serial-port, file-descriptor, single-threaded

For a serial protocol stack I'm going to implement two thread, one for reading from (and maybe writing to) serial, and the other thread only for writing.

I wonder if it is safe to open once and use the file descriptor in both threads, or it is better to open twice, like this:

```
tx_fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_WRONLY);
rx_fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDONLY);
```

or maybe I should use a different paradigm to do everything in single thread.

What are the pitfalls?

Comment: Either should work, I don't think it makes much difference. Opening twice means that you don't have to coordinate which thread closes it.

Comment: @Barmar *Either should work* Famous last words...  ;-)

Comment: I'm not in favour of opening things twice, especially with COM ports.  Be very careful.  If you are going to write in a separate thread, write ONLY in that thread.  If the read thread, or any other thread, wishes to send a bufferful of stuff, queue the buffer to the single write thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are "pitfalls" either way. In the single thread approach, you can read while writing, there can be some added latency to response times, but the code is generally simpler.  In multi-threaded arrangements, you can make progress in one or more threads while others are blocked and generally utilize a modern system more efficiently, but if any of the threads must share any data between them or otherwise require synchronization/coordination between operations, then you have to resort to using one or more of the following; pipes, queues, locks, semaphores, memory fences, etc.